# Filter for high amplitude noise

Tags: voltage, filter

I need some guidance and pointers for filters which filter out high amplitude noise. I have an analog signal coming from an IR pulse sensor which I would like to amplify further, but certain environmental artefacts produce noise which is significantly higher and reaching my top voltage limit for the ADC. I would like a filter where I can, say, block any signal above 4.5 Volts.

circuit below
[image: circuit]
<sub>(Image source: Goyal P., Udeshi M., Tallur S. - IIT Bombay, India (no date) - [*Heart Rate Measurement using PPG*][2])</sub>

Comment: How does your circuit look and what does the oscillogram of the signal look like? Clamp the signal to 4.5 V with a diode?

Comment: @winny Circuit posted. Its a simple wave, ADC value going from 150 to 950, but motion artefacts can be violent. I would just like to be cautious and prevent anything going above 1024 ADC value so my Arduino doesn't go nuclear. Is it possible?

Comment: Your opamp(s) will not output any higher voltage than the supply. If your Arduino and opamp share Vcc, the opamp will clip below Vcc and your Arduino is safe.

Comment: @winny thanks for letting me know, can be much more brave now. So this Op amp is powered between 5V and -5v, so I can keep adding as much amplification as I want??

Comment: -5 V can still fry your Arduino. Simulate worst case negative voltage you can get. Clamp it with Schottky diodes if needed.

Comment: @winny Ok, as in the schematic above, I am using a (regular) diode in the end output. Will replace it with a Schottky (I've got 1N5822) diode if you say. That should suffice?

Comment: @DribbleNibble - Hi, Please [edit] your question & cite ([reference](/help/referencing)) the source of that schematic. I found the source and added it to your [previous question](/q/657239) so you can use the same reference wording here. Please add references like that from now on, for material copied (or closely reworded/adapted) from elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: A simulation will tell you the answer ;-)

Comment: @SamGibson I've done it. But please tell how did you find the source? From my other posts or some other method? I'd like to know because many times I am looking for source material of schematic pics but can't find it.